# How to calculate sum of rows that is last 1-7, 8-14, 15-21 etc. by group in sql as separate columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I like to calculate sum of rows that is last 1-7, 8-14, 15-21 etc. by group in sql as separate columns:

**Input Data:**

[image]

**Expected Result:**

[image]

Comment: (1) Please provide your data as tabular text rather than images (2) Explain the logic that you want, in words - it is not obvious (3) Show us your attempt at solving this yourself

Comment: Thanks, its awesome !!! I have one more doubt, what if I have duplicates rows in the input table, Assume rows 2,3 and 4 are same and I should keep only 2nd row and delete 3 and 4 and perform other calculations parallel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use analytic functions:

```sql
SELECT t.*,
       CASE COUNT(*) OVER (
              PARTITION BY grp
              ORDER BY rw
              ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 6 FOLLOWING
            )
       WHEN 7
       THEN SUM( vol ) OVER (
              PARTITION BY grp
              ORDER BY rw
              ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 6 FOLLOWING
            )
       END AS last7,
       CASE COUNT(*) OVER (
              PARTITION BY grp
              ORDER BY rw
              ROWS BETWEEN 7 FOLLOWING AND 13 FOLLOWING
            )
       WHEN 7
       THEN SUM( vol ) OVER (
              PARTITION BY grp
              ORDER BY rw
              ROWS BETWEEN 7 FOLLOWING AND 13 FOLLOWING
            )
       END AS last8_14
FROM   table_name t
```

Which, for your sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( rw, grp, vol ) AS
SELECT  1, 'A', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  2, 'A', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  3, 'A', 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  4, 'A', 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  5, 'A', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  6, 'A', 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  7, 'A', 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  8, 'A', 5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  9, 'A', 5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 10, 'A', 6 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 11, 'A', 7 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 12, 'A', 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 13, 'A', 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 14, 'A', 5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 15, 'A', 4 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> RW | GRP | VOL | LAST7 | LAST8_14
> -: | :-- | --: | ----: | -------:
>  1 | A   |   1 |    19 |       35
>  2 | A   |   2 |    23 |       34
>  3 | A   |   3 |    26 |     null
>  4 | A   |   4 |    29 |     null
>  5 | A   |   2 |    32 |     null
>  6 | A   |   3 |    33 |     null
>  7 | A   |   4 |    34 |     null
>  8 | A   |   5 |    35 |     null
>  9 | A   |   5 |    34 |     null
> 10 | A   |   6 |  null |     null
> 11 | A   |   7 |  null |     null
> 12 | A   |   3 |  null |     null
> 13 | A   |   4 |  null |     null
> 14 | A   |   5 |  null |     null
> 15 | A   |   4 |  null |     null
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=98cc23ee72b9a899b9e1f97542ccec43)*